# Auto complete delete prior function names etc

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

While writing Python code, I think it is really frustrating that Visual Studio 2022 removes `range(`, the closing parenthesis and the colon when running auto complete in this example (when tabbing to get `demo_number`). Is this a bug or something that I can tweak?

[image]